# bash script, syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, syntax

I want to create a bash scripts that performs a certain task while checking if a file with a certain name. I am using UTF-8 encoding and running the script "bash test.sh". on a Ubuntu machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting..."
while true
do
  echo "In loop..."
  sleep 2

  if 
    -e "./droneControl.py"
  then
    break
  fi
done

echo "found..."
```

Comment: Your `if` needs to be in brackets: `if [ -e "./droneControl.py" ]`. Also why are you using a loop?

Comment: Your using "-e" as parameter for "if", it's a parameter for the "test" command. Try "if [[ -e ./drone control.py ]]".

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: I am using a while loop because I want it to continuously check if the file exist.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your script using `dos2unix` or an equivalent command.

```
$ bash fromnotepad.sh
fromnotepad.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
Starting...
fromnotepad.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ sed 's/\r$//' fromnotepad.sh > fromunix.sh

$ bash fromunix.sh
Starting...
In loop...
found...
```

Script:

```
$ cat fromunix.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting..."
while true
do
  echo "In loop..."
  sleep 2

  if [ -e "./ls.txt" ]
  then
    break
  fi
done

echo "found..."
```